# for loop only shows first item in array swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parameter-passing

I have a function called loadPosts that returns an array of Int values.  Upon running it is used within the UITableView which has a function called setCell.  Only the first item in the array is being used and then it repeats that value for the length of the array.

UPDATE 2: 
Here are the parameters within the hhmessages array:
    1. senderusername
    2. recipient
    3. message text 
    4. ava image

UPDATED: now includes additional code in loadPosts function

```
func loadPosts()->[Int] {
    let me = user!["username"] as! String
    let uuid = messages["uuid"] as! String
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/message.php")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let body = "username=\(me)&uuid=\(uuid)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if error == nil {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    self.hhmessages.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    // declare new parseJSON to store json
                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let messages = parseJSON["messages"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                        print("Error while parseJSONing")
                        return
                    }

                    self.hhmessages = messages
                    //print(self.hhmessages)

for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {
     if me == self.hhmessages[i]["senderusername"]!! as! String {
         self.incoming = [0]
 }
     if me == self.hhmessages[i]["recipient"]!! as! String {
         self.incoming = [1]
   }
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
return [Int()]
}
```

// UITableView

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell

    func setCell(incoming: [Int]) {

        var layoutAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute
        var layoutConstant: CGFloat
        for i in 0 ..< self.incoming.count {

            if (self.incoming[i] == 1) {
                cell.bubbleImageView.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "chat_bubble_received")
            cell.messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
            layoutAttribute = .left
            layoutConstant = 10
            cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleImageView, attribute: layoutAttribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: layoutConstant))
        }
           if (self.incoming[i] == 0) {
                cell.bubbleImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chat_bubble_sent")
        cell.messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
            layoutAttribute = .right
            layoutConstant = -10
        cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleImageView, attribute: layoutAttribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: layoutConstant))

        }
        }
    }
    // get main queue to this block of code to communicate back
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
        setCell(incoming: self.incoming)

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: your `return` integer array is correct ? do you mind to post an example of your `hhmessages` ?

Comment: @GIJOW thank you for responding.  Sure I can post the hhmessages.  I know the hhmessages are working as I can see the messages, they just aren't formatted based on the conditions set in setCell

Comment: @GIJOW I've included the additional code for hhmessages

Comment: sorry about the misunderstanding but I meant some content of `hhmessages` to understand the structure

Comment: @GIJOW Gotcha.  I'll post that now.

Comment: It looks like you are setting `self.incoming` to a single value, either `0` or `1`. Are you meaning to append the values to self.incoming?

Comment: @GIJOW - done updating.

Comment: @NateBirkholz I'm not trying to append the other values to incoming. Incoming should either be 1 or 0 to perform the conditional formatting of the message

Comment: @techgirl Trying to understand, here, to help, so sorry if I'm being dim, but `self.incoming` is always a single value. A count of 1. How are you determining the number of rows in the table? If it's not `self.incoming.count`, it would just be the same cell over and over again.

Comment: Basically, what does `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` look like? :)

Comment: @NateBirkholz thank you Nate. I truly appreciate any help you can provide. I'm fairly new so I'm just happy you responded. I'm determine the number of rows by the hhmessages.count. hhmessages holds the array values. Does that make sense?

Comment: @NateBirkholz numberofRowsInSection only contains this statement         'return hhmessages.count'

Comment: @techgirl That makes sense. So let's say `self.hhmessages` contains 10 values. You'd have 10 cells. But in `loadPosts()` you loop over all the hhmesages, and set `self.incoming` to be an array of one single item, either [0] or [1]. So `self.incoming` has a length of 1. when `cellForRowAt indexPath` goes to set up the cells, it just gets the same value over and over. I'm going to post a solution that I *think* meets your needs. We will see. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func loadPosts()->[Int] {
    let me = user!["username"] as! String
    let uuid = messages["uuid"] as! String
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost/message.php")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: url)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let body = "username=\(me)&uuid=\(uuid)"
    request.httpBody = body.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            if error == nil {

                do {

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

                    self.hhmessages.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()

                    // declare new parseJSON to store json
                    guard let parseJSON = json else {
                        print("Error while parsing")
                        return
                    }

                    guard let messages = parseJSON["messages"] as? [AnyObject] else {
                        print("Error while parseJSONing")
                        return
                }

                    self.hhmessages = messages
                    //print(self.hhmessages)

                    /// This is the part I edited
                    for i in 0 ..< self.hhmessages.count {
                        if me == self.hhmessages[i]["senderusername"]!! as! String {
                            self.incoming.append(0)
                        }
                        if me == self.hhmessages[i]["recipient"]!! as! String {
                            self.incoming.append(1)
                        }
                    }
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                    return [Int()]
 }
```

Change your `cellForRowAt` to use the `indexPath.row` as the index for `self.incoming` :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ConversationCell

    func setCell(incoming: [Int]) {

        var layoutAttribute: NSLayoutAttribute
        var layoutConstant: CGFloat

        if (self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 1) {
            cell.bubbleImageView.image=#imageLiteral(resourceName: "chat_bubble_received")
            cell.messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.black
            layoutAttribute = .left
            layoutConstant = 10
            cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleImageView, attribute: layoutAttribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: layoutConstant))
        }
        if (self.incoming[indexPath.row] == 0) {
            cell.bubbleImageView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "chat_bubble_sent")
            cell.messageLbl.textColor = UIColor.white
            layoutAttribute = .right
            layoutConstant = -10
            cell.contentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: cell.bubbleImageView, attribute: layoutAttribute, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: cell.contentView, attribute: layoutAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: layoutConstant))

        }
    }
// get main queue to this block of code to communicate back
    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -CGFloat.pi)
        cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
        setCell(incoming: self.incoming)

    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me.  I went through the results.  hhmessages has 54 rows (messages), incoming should be 1 a total of 7 times based on the data and 0 the remaining.  I incorporate your awesome suggestion but it resulted in a sequence of 1s and 0s that looped through 54 times. The conditional formatting still didn't go through. It's as if the first 'incoming' gets to the formatting condition but no others.  Make sense?

Comment: So all 54 message are still the same bubble?

Comment: They are in separate bubbles but all the same format and side.  If incoming is 1 then they should be gray bubbles, if 0 they should be purple.

Comment: @techgirl I'm very puzzled. Your layout code *looks* like it should be working! I'm going to try to recreate your project based on what I know so far. This should take a little bit though. :)

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. :(

Comment: @techgirl figured it out, I should have seen it sooner, silly me. Check out the revised answer

Comment: IT WORKED.  You're the real MVP.  Thank you so so much.